# pySerial sending and receiving multiple data

Tags: python, arduino, arduino-uno, pyserial

I have a question about sending and receiving multiple data using the pySerial Python library. According to what I understand, serial port communication works with byte variables.

How do I send four different variables with method `write` and then with method `read` receive two different variables?

As an example:

```
import serial
import time

sendSerial = serial.Serial ("COM4", 9600)
readoutSerial = serial.Serial ("COM4", 9600)
time.sleep (2)
sendSerial.write ("data1" + "data2" + "data3" + "data4")
while True:
    readoutSerial.read ("data5" + "data6")
```

What should I do to send the four variables with `write` differentiated by some character and then separate them for the respective use of each variable? (applying the same for the two variables received with `read`) Also, what can I do to send the variables as`float` and not generate conflict with the reading in `byte`?

Comment: How is this related to [`tkinter`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tkinter/info)?

Comment: Through `tkinter` I have a graphical interface where the values of the variables are entered and read

Comment: For avoiding send and get conflict, you can use .mutex() in threading library

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are transporting text, the easies way is to pick some character to separate individual strings, it can be \n(newline), comma or anything.

```
ser = serial.Serial ("COM4", 9600)
ser.write(b"some string\n")
ser.write(b"some other string\n")
```

Reading of text in python will be like this:

```
s1 = ser.readline()
```

On arduino, you will read the string like this(primitive example):

```
char buf[64];
int bufIdx = 0;
while(Serial.peek() != '\n') { // Continue till the end of line
  if(Serial.peek() != -1) { // If no char arrived in this loop, skip.
    buf[bufIdx] = Serial.read();
    bufIdx = (bufIdx + 1) % 64; // Wrap around, so it will not go crazy string too long
  }
}
buf[bufIdx] = '\0'; // End of string char
```

Or if you don't mind using strings on Arduino(you most likely don't), you might be better of using [readStringUntil](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/ReadStringUntil) function:

```
string str1 = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
string str2 = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
```

In python, you can even convert numerical values into text:

```
textStr = str(1234)
```

On Arduino side, you can receive numbers as a string like this:

```
int x = Serial.parseInt(); // Receives (string)"1234", returns (int)1234
float y = Serial.parseFloat(); // Receives (string)"1.24E13", returns (float)1.24E13
```

---

If you need to transport structured binary data, python has a module called [struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html), that is the recomended way to do it in python. On arduino side, you will most likely have to shuffle bytes manualy. For example, int16 would be received like this:

```
while(Serial.available() < 2); // Block, until at least 2 bytes are received
int int16;
int16 = Serial.read() | (Serial.read()<<8); // Little-endian, low byte first, high byte second
```

Comment: I haven't tested your code but as a new user, it was pretty elaborate of you. Keep up the good work! +1

Answer (score 1):

Using **mutex(Lock)** to avoid send and receive conflict:

```
import serial
import time
from threading import Lock

mutex = Lock() 

sendSerial = serial.Serial ("COM4", 9600)
readoutSerial = serial.Serial ("COM4", 9600)
time.sleep (2)

mutex.acquire()
try:
    sendSerial.write ("data1" + "data2" + "data3" + "data4")
except:
    pass
finally:
    self.mutex.release()

while True:
    with mutex:
        readoutSerial.read ("data5" + "data6")
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Store the strings in a variable such as:

   - var = "data1\r" + "data2\r" + "data3\r" + "data4\r"
2. Then send the above concatenated string in a for loop

   - for i in range len(var):
     sendSerial.write (var)

This worked for me while I was playing around with the serial port of PSoc using a python script.

Comment: Try formatting the code in your answer: selecting it and then press Ctrl+k.